# Powershell if-statement passing in parameter

Tags: powershell

```
param($addr)
$file = get-content $addr

if($addr -eq $null){
        "Please use a valid parameter"
}
else{
        if ($addr -ne './*'){
                write-host $addr
        }
        else{
                write-host $file
        }

}
```

OUPUT:

```
./ipAddress.txt
```

CONTENT:

```
8.8.8.8
127.0.0.1
208.67.222.222
```

If I put `$file` out of the if statement then it works. However, I want to be able to say if the user inputs either a file or an ip address then do this...

Comment: What's the failure when you leave `$file` in?

Comment: It simply outputs the file name, i need the contents of the file. Sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: So, assuming you're calling this script `Get-Stuff.ps1`, you're calling it as `.\Get-Stuff.ps1 .\ipAddress.txt` and instead of pulling the content of the file, it's just printing the file name?

Comment: the format would be `./get-Ping.ps1 ./ipAddress.txt `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your comparison in the `else` clause. `-ne` only matches - or rather, not-matches - an exact string, without honoring wildcards. Instead, you should use `-notlike`: `if ($addr -notlike "./*") {...}`. Note that you'll still have problems if you supply a full path to a file (e.g., `D:\Foo\IPs.txt`), but the comparison here is your specific problem given the input for your example.

Take a look at [`Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators.)

Comment: If there was a way give someone a hug over a computer, you sir deserve one. Thank you for your contribution :)

Comment: If it worked for you, click on the checkmark below the vote for the answer. It marks the question as solved (and gives me a few points of reputation).

Answer (score 4):

Stop relying on positional parameters. Use named parameters with parameter sets, and remove the ambiguity:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='ByFile')]
param(
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$true,
        ParameterSetName='ByFile'
    )]
    [ValidateScript( { $_ | Test-File } )]
    [String]
    $Path ,

    [Parameter(
        Mandatory=$true,
        ParameterSetName='ByIP'
    )]
    [System.Net.IPAddress[]]
    $IPAddress
)

$ipAddresses = if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'ByFile') {
    $Path | Get-Content
} else {
    $IPAddress
}

foreach ($ip in $ipAddresses) {
    # do something with the IP
}
```

Invoke it like this:

```
./get-Ping.ps1 -File ./fileOfIPs.txt
```

or

```
./get-Ping.ps1 -IPAddress 10.1.2.3
./get-Ping.ps1 -IPAddress 10.0.0.10,10.0.0.20,8.8.8.8
```

It even supports multiple IPs given directly.

### Alternative

If you must support a positional parameter that can be either, then I suggest testing the IP first:

```
param($addr)

$ips = if ($addr -as [System.Net.IPAddress]) { # it can be interpreted as an IP
    $addr
} else {
    $addr | Get-Content
}

foreach ($ip in $ips) {
    #do something
}
```

Comment: This is a good (dare I say 'best'?) practice, and one that I would recommend on general principles, but it's also an advanced technique which I suspect the querent wasn't quite up to.